# TeamCity Socket timeout When Creating Database

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, timeoutexception

I am using TeamCity version 10.4. I am trying to create the database on my local machine.

[image]

However, I am getting this error:

```
  The connection to the host localhost, named instance hsalman-pc failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out".
 Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later,
 verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
```

I have the required driver here:

[image]

Aslo, I cannot locate the database properties file in the data directory. So what is the problem?